# vue-router when reloading the page at the home page, redirects me login page

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

After login, router successfully redirects me home(Index). When I reload the page at the home(Index), router redirects me login page again. Here is my router/index.js:

```
import { useAuthenticationStore } from "@/store/modules/auth";
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from "vue-router";
import Index from "../views/IndexView.vue";
import Login from "../views/LoginView.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: Index,
  },
  {
    path: "/login",
    name: "login",
    component: Login,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const store = useAuthenticationStore();
  if (store.status === false && to.name !== "login") {
    next({ name: "login" });
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

Where am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Your app does not persist data across reloads unless you make it persist.  When you reload, `store.status` is going to be it's default value, probably `false`.  Research a strategy to persist data that suits your app and implement it.  [Here](https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/refresh-proof-your-pinia-stores/) is an article with 3 methods assuming you're using Pinia for your store.